# How to check if the letter is the same after every uppercase letter?

Tags: java, regex

**Task:**

> Write a function that receives an expression, which consists only of the clauses('a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C') as a string or array of characters and returns a boolean representing if the expression is valid or invalid.

**Examples: input - output**

- AaBb - true
- BCAacb - true
- BCcAab - true
- ACABbBbaca - true
- AabB - false
- BCAcaB - false

This is my code:

```
public class Main {
private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter phrase");
    String inputExpression = scanner.nextLine();

    //checkPhraseTrueOrFalse(inputPhrase);
    System.out.println(isValidExpression(inputExpression));
}

public static boolean isValidExpression(String expression) {
    String[] splitInputExpressionExp = expression.split("@", 2);
    for (String s : splitInputExpressionExp) {
        if (s.contains("Aa") || s.contains("Bb") || s.contains("Cc")) {
            if ((!s.contains("Aa") || !s.contains("Bb") || !s.contains("Cc"))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

How to modify the `isValidExpression` method?

Comment: I don't see any use of Regular Expression. Why is the question tagged [regex]? Are you looking for a regex solution or was that a mis-tag?

Comment: Yes i look for regex solution.

Comment: Like this? `\b(?:[ABC]+[abc]+)+\b` https://regex101.com/r/tibSmB/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird will return true for "BBa". The question does not contain this example, but from what I understood that is not a valid input (all valid examples contain the same number of upper and lowercase letters and each uppercase letter has a matching lowercase letter)

Comment: The question is clear to me. I do not understand **Needs details or clarity** as the reason for the Close Vote to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repeat matching 0+ uppercase chars, and repeat matching either Ab Bb or Cc followed by optional lowercase chars.

To prevent partial matches you can use a word boundary `\b`

```
\b(?:[ABC]*(?:Aa|Bb|Cc)[abc]*)+\b
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[ABC]*` Match optional uppercase chars `A` `B` `C`
  - `(?:Aa|Bb|Cc)` Match 1 of the alternatives
  - `[abc]*` Match optional lowercase chars `a` `b` `c`
- `)+` Close the group  and repeat 1+ times
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J65isT/1)

In Java with the doubled backslashes

```
String regex = "\\b(?:[ABC]*(?:Aa|Bb|Cc)[abc]*)+\\b";
```